# Graph.Chart interop in Word

Tags: c#, charts, interop, ms-word

I'm having massive problems when trying to update a chart through MSWord interop. All I want to do is set the values on a chart in a word document so the graph can update to values in my app.

I've done the following (after importing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.dll):

```
InlineShape chartShape = WordDocument.InlineShapes[2];
chartShape.Activate(); // for opening Chart in edit mode

// Convert the InlineShape into Chart type which is a part of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart oChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.Chart) chartShape.OLEFormat.Object;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Graph.DataSheet dataSheet = oChart.Application.DataSheet;

dataSheet.Cells[1, 1] = 10;
```

Firstly it throws a COMException (That metod is not available on that object) on the Activate() method. If I hope over that, the actual OLEFormat.Object throws an InvalidCastException (the specified cast is not valid).

Anyhow managed to get something like this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your InlineShape a "MSGraph.Chart.8"?

Do not use the .Activate(), you need to make sure the OLE object is in a running state (I think this is why you get the invalid cast).

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape chartShape = aDoc.InlineShapes[1];
if (chartShape.OLEFormat.ProgID == "MSGraph.Chart.8")
{
    object verb = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOLEVerb.wdOLEVerbHide;
    chartShape.OLEFormat.DoVerb(ref verb);
    Graph.Chart oChart = (Graph.Chart)chartShape.OLEFormat.Object;
    Graph.DataSheet dataSheet = oChart.Application.DataSheet;
    dataSheet.Cells[1, 1] = 10;
}
```