# Generate a chart in .NET and include it in a Word file

Tags: .net, ms-word

I generate a MS Word document with the .NET application. I use merge fields and stuff like this.

Now, I have some data that I should represent in a chart (string-double collection).

I need to include this chart into that Word document.

How should I proceed? I suppose I should generate an image and include it in the document.

Is there a way to generate charts(images) with a specific "skin" in .NET?

Comment: how would you like to generate it? You can use XtraChart from DevExpress and export the chart as image then include the image in the word document... or do you have other ideas?

Comment: @Davide Piras: I am searching here the ideas )) No idea but draw an image in GDI+ and have a Picture object as output.

Answer (score 4):

If you are already interacting with Word using their interop library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) then I think you can directly use its charts too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.chart.aspx

[Graph.Chart interop in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555145/graph-chart-interop-in-word)

I've done this with Excel in the past (set a bunch of data in a grid then chart it) but not in Word, so i don't have any example code, sorry.

Comment: I have some server side code that should generate this chart from some data. Can I have the image WITHOUT displaying the chart to the user (in a Web or Win Form)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Aspose.Cells and Aspose.Words for .NET? You can [create a chart and convert it to image using Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/converting-chart-to-image.html). You can also [add the converted image to Word document using Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/inserting-document-elements.html). This doesn't require MS Office to be installed on the server. Please see if this might help in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I have some server side code that should generate this chart from some data. Can I have the image WITHOUT displaying the chart to the user (in a Web or Win Form)?

Comment: Definitely. The chart is actually created via code and you can either save it on the server or further use it in your application, without any user intervention or showing it to the user.